# How does TF-IDF produce features for machine-learning ? What is different from a bag of words?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I was hoping to get a brief explanation of how TF-IDF produces features that can be used for machine learning. What are the differences between bag of words and TF-IDF? I understand how TF-IDF works; but not how features are made with it and how these are used in classification/regression.

I am using scikit-learn; what does the following code actually do theoretically and in practice? I have commented it with my understanding and some questions, any help would be really appreciated :

```
  traindata = list(np.array(p.read_table('data/train.tsv'))[:,2]) #taking in data for TF-IDF, I get this
  testdata = list(np.array(p.read_table('data/test.tsv'))[:,2]) #taking in data for TF-IDF, I get this
  y = np.array(p.read_table('data/train.tsv'))[:,-1] #labels for our data

  tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode',  
        analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1) #making tf-idf object with params to dictate how it should behave

  rd = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=True, tol=0.0001, 
                             C=1, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, 
                             class_weight=None, random_state=None) 

  X_all = traindata + testdata #adding data together
  lentrain = len(traindata) #what is this?
  tfv.fit(X_all) #is this where features are created? Are all words used as features? What happens here ?
  X_all = tfv.transform(X_all)#transforms our numpy array of text into a TF-IDF
  X = X_all[:lentrain]
  X_test = X_all[lentrain:]
  rd.fit(X,y) #train LR on newly made feature set with a feature for each word?
```

Comment: `traindata + testdata` will not concatenate matrices but will try to sum the content of the matrices, dont't do that.

Also don't call `tfv.fit(X_all)` Using test data in the training phase is cheating and can potentially hide overfitting. Instead do: `X_train = tfv.fit_transform(traindata)` to learn the word to feature mapping (the vocabulary) and then transform the test set with the same vectorizer instance: `X_test = tfv.transform(testdata)`.

Comment: To concatenate 2 sparse matrices, use `scipy.sparse.vstack([A, B])` for vertical stacking or `scipy.sparse.hstack([A, B])` for horizontal stacking.

Comment: This code is a bad usage example, read the official documentation and the linked examples instead: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction

Comment: @ogrisel This is code adapted from code which won a Kaggle competition (I am playing with it just to learn)...so I don't believe it should be bad practice!

Comment: @SimonKiely It is bad practice. By fitting the vectorizer to the full set, you're learning from the test set. It may not overfit very badly for large training sets and small test sets, but it's still methodologically flawed and unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: @larsmans Is this not called semi-supervised learning and is considered acceptable now? Several textbooks I have read allude to this being traditionally bad practice but now acceptable. I do not understand why this has been voted down.

Comment: Semisupervised learning is when you use additional unlabeled data, not when you train on the test set, even if you only train part of your model on it. The test set is supposed to simulate *unseen* data, to test generalization performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess idf is what make you confused here, since bag of words is the tf of word in the document, so why idf ? idf is a way to estimate how important the word is, usually, document frequency (df) is a good way to estimate how important a word in classfication, since when a word appear in less document (nba would always appear in documents belong to sports) show a better descrimination, so idf is in positive correlation to word's importance.

Answer (score 0):

Tf-idf is the most common vector representation for documents. It takes into account the frequencies of the words in a text and also in the whole document corpus.
Obviously, this method is not scientifically backed, this means that it pragmatically works well in a bunch of contexts, like document similarity using cosine distance or other types of metrics, but was not derived from a mathematical proof.